# Is the `extends` property deprecated in X-Tag?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, x-tag

The use-case for the extends property seems very straight-forward (http://www.x-tags.org/docs#custom-tag-registration-extends), however testing with the following, tag definition:

```
(function () {
    xtag.register('dk-foo', {
        extends: 'b',
        lifecycle: {
            created: function () {
                this.innerHTML = '*FOO*';
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

and markup:

```
<dk-foo>Hello BAR</dk-foo>
```

there doesn't seem to be any effect (i.e. the text is not bold), and worse, it breaks on Chrome.

I've tested IE11, FF28, Safari 5.1.17, and Chrome 33/35.  Every browser, except Chrome, runs code in `lifecycle.created` (i.e. changes the text to `*FOO*`).  If I remove the `extends` property it runs on Chrome as well.

I haven't been able to find any more documentation on `extends` than the documentation above, nor any tags that uses it (although I certainly haven't looked at all of them...).

Am I perhaps just using the `extends` property incorrectly..?

Comment: Same exact issue here.  I raised an issue : https://github.com/x-tag/core/issues/76

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/x-tag/core/issues/76#issuecomment-41218168):

> When you extend an element, you need to use the is="" syntax in your
> markup: . The is="" attribute is part of the standard,
> it's the only way to create custom elements from native elements.

I tried it and you actually need `is=` *and* the `extends`.  I don't like the `is=` so I'm actually just creating an inner element, in your case, an inner `b`.

Comment: Thanks for filing this. I'm getting the sense that extends is not going to save you any time/effort based on the latest comment on the bug: "It probably isn't testing anything you need it to at the moment, because while you *can* use an existing native element prototype as your base, none of its methods will work on the newly created `<x-whatever>` element you make."